# Enviar datos al controlador con JSF

Tags: java, mvc, jsf

estoy con una funcionalidad de apuntarse a una actividad, para ello, en cada actividad tengo un botón apuntarse, que llama al controlador correspondiente:

[image: Tabla]

Debajo del botón hay un campo input en el que indico el id de la actividad a la que se quiere apuntar el usuario y al lado del saludo vemos el id del usuario.

```
<h:column>                  
    <f:facet name = "header">Apuntarse</f:facet>                    
    <h:commandButton value="Apuntarse" action="#{controladorParticipaciones.apuntarse}" />
    <h:inputHidden id="idActividad" value="#{actividad.id}"/>
</h:column>
```

Y el código del controlador es:

```java
package controlador.control_Participaciones;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import modelo.Actividad;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ControladorActividades
 */
@WebServlet("/ControladorParticipaciones")
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ControladorParticipaciones extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Resource(lookup="jdbc/practica1")
    private DataSource miPool;
    private long idUsuario;
    private long idActividad;
    private Actividad activity;

    public String apuntarse() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        boolean encontrada = false;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Actividad> actividades = (List<Actividad>) context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("actividades");
        for (Actividad actividad_aux : actividades) {
            if(actividad_aux.getId() == idActividad) {
                context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("actividad", actividad_aux);
                activity = actividad_aux;
                encontrada = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!encontrada) {
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("msg", "No hemos podido encontrar la actividad");
            return "error";
        }
        return "apuntarse";

    }

    public long getIdUsuario() {
        return idUsuario;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(long idUsuario) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }

    public long getIdActividad() {
        return idActividad;
    }

    public void setIdActividad(long idActividad) {
        this.idActividad = idActividad;
    }

    public Actividad getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    public void setActivity(Actividad activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
}
```

El valor de la variable indicada con una flecha es siempre 0, pero yo quiero que sea el valor del campo input, se hacerlo si es el usuario el que rellena el input (lo he hecho en el login) pero no se hacerlo si quiero que JSF rellene el input, ya que el campo Value del input es diferente...

¿Cómo puedo pasarle al controlador el valor del id de la actividad? ya sea con un input o de otro modo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente que tu método apuntarse reciba el parámetro idActividad y se lo pasas directamente desde el action. No necesitas el input hidden:

```
         <h:commandButton value="Apuntarse" action="#{controladorParticipaciones.apuntarse(actividad.id}" />
```

Y el controlador:

```
         public String apuntarse(String idActividad) {



            }
```

Tambien podrias pasar el objeto actividad si es más conveniente. Ese dato lo puedes actualizar vía f:ajax en el commandButtom.

EDICION:

Ojo si tu método retorna un string en este caso "apuntarse" vas ha refrescar toda la página  . En cambio si retornas NULL te quedas en ella y podrías utilizar f:ajax para actualizar algunos datos.

EDICION 2:

La verdad no se si es inputHidden, supuestamente no es visible pero en tu  gráfica se visualiza.

EDICION 3:
Si es inputHidden entonces Pasa el objeto actividad y te libras de tanta busqueda:

```
      <h:commandButton value="Apuntarse" action="#{controladorParticipaciones.apuntarse(actividad)}" />
```

Y el controlador:

```
         public String apuntarse(Actividad actividad) {



            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a mi pregunta, he encontrado varias formas de hacerlo, pero creo que la más eficaz es enviar los valores como parámetros al método:

```
<h:commandButton value="Apuntarse" action="#{controladorParticipaciones.apuntarse(actividad.id)}" />
```

Y en el controlador:

```java
public String apuntarse(long idActividad) {
...
```